# Problema com AutoMapper relação muitos para muitos C#

Tags: c#, automapper

Tenho duas classes com uma relação de muitos para muitos, todo o mapeamento já está pronto, a inserção está funcionando, porém quando tento fazer o AutoMapper ele entra em um loop infinito.

Workflow:

```
    public class Workflow : Elemento
    {
        public IList<EventoWorkflow> EventosWorkflow;
    }
```

EventoWorkflow:

```
    public class EventoWorkflow : Evento
    {
        public IList<Workflow> Workflows;
    }
```

Tentei várias coisas que achei na internet para tentar fazer funcionar mas nenhuma delas deu certo, a ultima tentativa que fiz ficou assim:

Workflow -> WorkflowDTO

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Workflow, WorkflowDTO>()
                .ForMember(x => x.EventosWorkflow, m => m.MapFrom(w => w.EventosWorkflow.Select(y => y.ActualObject).ToList()));
```

EventoWorkflow -> EventoWorkflowDTO

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<EventoWorkflow, EventoWorkflowDTO>()
                    .ConstructUsing(x => new EventoWorkflowDTO(x.CodigoEvento, AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<Workflow>, List<WorkflowDTO>>(x.Workflows)));
```

Mas mesmo assim ele continua dando o erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'

Alguém sabe como posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Poste também seus classes DTO, porfavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só dar um `.Ignore()` nas classes relacionadas para parar o loop infinito.
Com isso, vai fazer as relações virem `null`, então você deve trabalhar com os dados desta forma.